# AWS ElasticSearch Service throws 403 forbidden on document insert

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, elasticsearch, hive

I am trying to upload data into AWS ElasticSearch using hive query.
The Intermediate table used within Hive query has following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE uid_taxonomy_1_day_es(
UID String
,VISITS INT
,TAXONOMY_LABEL_1 INT
,TAXONOMY_LABEL_2 INT
,TAXONOMY_LABEL_3 INT
,DAY_OF_YEAR INT)
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES('es.nodes' = 'https://search-cust-360-view-
6cj2j4mcytbtrpodzffnh3uadi.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com', 'es.port' = '443', 
'es.index.auto.create' = 'false', 'es.batch.size.entries' = '1000', 
'es.batch.write.retry.count' = '10000', 'es.batch.write.retry.wait' = '10s', 
'es.batch.write.refresh' = 'false','es.nodes.discovery' = 
'false','es.nodes.client.only' = 'false', 'es.resource' = 
'urltaxonomy/uids', 'es.query' = '?q=*', 'es.nodes.wan.only' = 'true');
```

The actual load query takes around half hour in loading the data.
And so in between at some random record it will throw 403 forbidden error.

Here is the stacktrace.

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: [HEAD] on [urltaxonomy] failed; server[https://search-cust-360-view-6cj2j4mcytbtrpodzffnh3uadi.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443] returned [403|Forbidden:]
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:505)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.executeNotFoundAllowed(RestClient.java:476)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.exists(RestClient.java:537)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.touch(RestClient.java:543)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.touch(RestRepository.java:412)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.initSingleIndex(RestService.java:606)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:594)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.init(EsOutputFormat.java:173)
```

The error happens only intermittently by which mean if i try to insert that failed record, it works fine.

I am thinking its some thing to do with my intermediate table structure.